# Datatable select concat two columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have some data in the datatable there are two columns that are
year and month that I need to concat and select the data

it should be some thing like this

```
DataTable dt;
string expression = (year,month)=(2009,03)
dt.Select(expression);
```

The above syntax is an example of what I want to achieve .

For further clarification I have the data in data table as

```
year | Month
2009   03
2010   04
2010   05
```

So the above select should fetch me one row.

Comment: Can you concat during SQL query (like: SELECT year + ' ' + month FROM...)?

Comment: Why not do the concatenation when the data is to be displayed instead?

Comment: See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1163327.aspx/1) question i think it will solve your problem

Comment: No i cannot concat the data in sql server

Answer (score 0):

you can get this by

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "year='2009' AND Month='03'";
```

Now **dt.DefaultView** will return you one row or rows matching your criteria

Comment: i have to combine both the columns and get the data

Comment: you achieve the same here, any specific reason why you want to concatenate them ?